# How are bounding box proposals generated in Google's paper "Deep Neural Networks for Object Detection"?

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection

[Paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/713f/73ce5c3013d9fb796c21b981dc6629af0bd5.pdf) mentioned in the question title deals with localization of certain objects in images. Paper mentions generating multiple types of object masks using deep neural network based on ImageNet, proposing multiple bounding boxes and scoring such proposals. However I can not find how the bounding box proposals are generated. If paper does not mention this method, what kind of algorithm would you suggest to generate such proposals?

Answer (score 2):

Section "4 Detection as DNN Regression" explains that they used a neural network to obtain the bounding boxes:

[image]

Comment: This section mentions that they use DNN generate binary masks. I'm interested in the bounding boxes, called _bb_ in the paper specified by their top left corner and bottom right corner. This is mentioned in section "5.2 Object Localization from DNN Output" but no method to obtain the bounding box propositions is mentioned, only their scoring.

Comment: @JakubPetriska the binary mask IS the bounding box, you could calculate  the box from this information, or maybe add a layer on top to do it for you.

Comment: @CristianGarcia How would a layer generating the bounding box on top of the binary mask layer look like?

Comment: @JakubPetriska I would propose a binary layer that learned to predict the position of e.g. the upper left corner and lower right pixels of the full (completely filled) bounding box binary mask suggested in the paper. In the end you are just doing very specific corner detection.